# Program not matching strings with words in text file

Tags: python

I have the following program in Python. It is intended to automatically unscramble Caesar Cipher codes by checking the words against the attached dictionary (words.txt) and outputting the correct one.

However, even though I can see that the lines are the same (for example, I can see by debugging that the string is 'hello' and the line in the text file is 'hello' it's showing as not having found a match. I've stripped newlines but am assuming that there is something else invisible in the text file that is causing the issue.

The formatting of the text file is each word on an individual line. The issue seems to be at the line which says

```
if line == possibilities[i][j]:
```

But I can't seem to figure out what the problem is

```
import string

words = []
possibilities = [[]*1 for i in range(26)]
possStrings = []
startPos = -1
nextPos = 0
temp = []
count = 0
uppers = []

print("Please enter your scrambled text")
crypt =  str(input())
crypt = crypt.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))


for i in range(len(crypt)):
    if crypt[i].isupper():
        uppers.append(True)
    else:
        uppers.append(False)
    if (i > 1 and crypt[i] == " ") or (i == len(crypt)-1):
        if (i == len(crypt)-1):
            nextPos = i+1
        else:
            nextPos = i
        words.append(crypt[startPos+1:nextPos])
        startPos = i

for i in range(26):
    for word in words:
        for j in range(len(word)):
            a = ord(word[j])
            a += i
            if a > 122:
                a -= 26
            temp.append(chr(a))
        possibilities[i].append(''.join(temp))
        temp = []
        count += 1

probability = [0]*25
with open("words.txt", "r") as dictionary:
  for i in range(25):
      for j in range(len(words)):
        for line in dictionary:
            line = line.strip('\n')
            if line == possibilities[i][j]:
                probability[i] += 1
        if probability[i] == len(words):
            break

print(probability)
winner = probability.index(max(probability))
if winner == 0:
    print("No match was found for this sentence")
else:
    print("The closest match to this sentence is", '"'+' '.join(possibilities[winner])+'"')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine with these changes:

1_ Seek the file handler "dictionary"(you might want to use a better name here for less confusion), back to the beginning of the `words.txt` file using:

```
dictionary.seek(0)
```

on the line 50 (after the loop in the lines of the file).

2_ The `index` method raises a ValueError if it doesn't find a match. (Read the help like this: `python3 -c "help([].index)"`). So you can do:

```
try:
    if max(probability) > 0:
        winner = probability.index(max(probability))
        print("The closest match to this sentence is", '"'+' '.join(possibilities[winner])+'"')
    else:
        raise ValueError
except ValueError:
    print("No match was found for this sentence")
```

Now with the changes made:

```
> Please enter your scrambled text
gdkkn zcdqbgnw
The closest match to this
sentence is "hello aderchox"
```

complete working code: https://pastebin.com/76HkEZi6

---

- Also on line 13, you don't need the `str()`, as the input() itself gives you an string(although that doesn't make any difference).
- Nothing is wrong with the line `if line == possibilities[i][j]:`. You can simply try that with `python3 -c 'print("test" == "test")'`.

---

Also, instead of the for loop between the lines 17 to 28, you could get the list of lower cased words in the input sentence with a one liner as simple as this:

```
words = list(map(str.lower,crypt.split()))
```

HTH.